# Solaris: is possible to permit root login on some terms?

Tags: security, solaris, root, tty, smf

I have a server with some serial ports.
One is /dev/console, another is /dev/term/b(the ttyS1 under linux and the COM2 under dos).
I want root to login under /dev/term/b but..

```
myserver termb login: root
Password: 
Not on system console

myserver termb login:
```

An easy solution is to edit `/etc/default/login` and comment the line `CONSOLE`
but with this solution root login is allowed on ALL ports,
I want to permit access root on `/dev/console`, `/dev/term/b`
but not on `/dev/term/a` or `/dev/pts/*` for example.
On some good old unix and unix-like(Sco,BSD,Slackware)
we have to edit `/etc/securetty` and enable the line
where we want grant root access..and on Solaris?
Solaris version is 11.4 and root is normal user and not role.

Comment: Do you believe that login.c from OpenSolaris is OK for you?

Comment: I don't like this solution

Comment: Then you seem to have a problem that you cannot solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in Solaris 11 managed thru smf.

So: that is the values in the svc:/system/security/account-policy:default ?

What do

```
svcprop -p login_policy/root_login_device svc:/system/security/account-policy:default
```

say ?

The interesting property/attribute seems to be login_policy/root_login_device so
could that accept something like:
/dev/console,/dev/term/b  ie a list of values.

```
svccfg -s svc:/system/security/account-policy:default setprop login_policy/root_login_device="/dev/console,/dev/term/b"
```

Is an example of how i think you could modify this property.

```
svccfg -s svc:/system/security/account-policy:default setprop login_policy/root_login_device="/dev/term/b"
```

Is another idea, in this case root should only be allowed on term/b.

I don't have access to a (Open)Solaris system now so...  i could install something like Indiana or Nexenta.

account-policy:default well it is possible in SMF to define nodes which inherits its properties from a super class.

You really needs to read up on SMF but it exists a number of blog posts and other stuff except the man-pages and the system administration books which explains SMF.

See also :
http://www.unixrock.com/2014/07/how-to-allow-root-direct-login-in.html
[smf]

Comment: Good answer, works fine. Only the "path" were different, instead of `svc:/system/security/account-policy:default` Solaris now use `vc:/system/account-policy:default`

Comment: I mean `svc:/system/account-policy:default`

Comment: One problem about the system admin pages is that it doesn't really explain (i haven't found it yet) instead it is (usually) examples of modifications on a running system.  Less how to  correctly design a manifest, this could be covered in the development documents.

Comment: How can i add a tag like solaris/solarissmf ?

Comment: i found out how to add a tag...

Comment: I have added the tag smf